# Angular 5 - Pass Api data from component to another

Tags: php, angular, typescript

**TL;DR:** What i want to do is get the data from an input of a component form and then compare it via an API services and after that, from the field of the form(which is called correo) i want to pass to it to another component,  which i want to fetch it in a variable and using a http.post for sending it to another API and fetch the data in the other component
They have been telling me i have to use DataService  but still i don't get it how to use it well.

Any help? 
I can share if you want to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an example of a data service here: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter-routing:

Here is the `getMovies` method as an example. You can check out my github for the other CRUD operations.

**Data access service**

```
@Injectable()
export class MovieService {
    private moviesUrl = 'api/movies';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getMovies(): Observable<IMovie[]> {
        return this.http.get<IMovie[]>(this.moviesUrl);
    }
}
```

**In the component:**

```
getMovies(): void {
    this.movieService.getMovies()
        .subscribe(
            (movies: IMovie[]) => this.movies = movies,
            (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```